# How to shuffle a python list such that the occurrence of some elements are preserved?

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

I start with a list of integers:

A = [ 1, 2, **5, 3, 4**, 6, 7, 8 ]

After a shuffle, I would like some elements (say 3, 4 and 5) to preserve their order of occurrence in A while the rest of the elements are free to be randomly shuffled. Something like:

Outcome #1:
A = [ **5**, 2, **3**, 1, 8, **4**, 6, 7 ]

-or-

Outcome #2:
A = [ 7, **5**, 6, 1, **3**, **4**, 8, 2 ]

-but not-

Outcome #3 (invalid outcome)
A = [7, **4**, 6, 1, **3**, **5**, 8, 2]

Appreciate all suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you made any attempt at solving this? If so, can you share the code as a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: it's unclear what you want to achieve. what difference do you make between location and occurrence?  what you show as expected output is exactly what `randon.shuffle(your_list)` would yield.

Comment: The spec seems clear, OP wants the 5 -> 3 -> 4 sublist to never change order, so `[7, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 8, 2]` would be an invalid outcome. Or so I assume.

Comment: that's the problem - it's your/our assumption

Comment: Welcome to SO

would give us some code so we can copy and pest in our development environment to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the elements you want to maintain relative ordering among, shuffle as normal, then glue the lists back together by randomly picking indexes for the "kept" elements to be inserted. All operations are linear if you use sets for speeding up `in` operations, which I didn't bother with. Ordering of the `keep` list matters.

```
>>> import random
>>> L = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
>>> keep = [2, 3, 4]
>>> kept = [L[i] for i in keep][::-1]
>>> unkept = [x for i, x in enumerate(L) if i not in keep]
>>> random.shuffle(unkept)
>>> idxes = random.sample(list(range(len(L))), k=len(keep))
>>> result = [kept.pop() if i in idxes else unkept.pop() for i in range(len(L))]
>>> result
[6, 5, 3, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2]
```

Random tests:

```
import random

def shuffle_with_fixed_order(L, keep):
    kept = [L[i] for i in keep][::-1]
    unkept = [x for i, x in enumerate(L) if i not in keep]
    random.shuffle(unkept)
    idxes = random.sample(list(range(len(L))), k=len(keep))
    return [kept.pop() if i in idxes else unkept.pop() for i in range(len(L))]
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(5000):
        L = list(range(50))
        random.shuffle(L)
        keep = sorted(random.sample(L, k=20))
        shuffled = shuffle_with_fixed_order(L, keep)
        new_locs = [shuffled.index(L[i]) for i in keep]
        assert all(x < y for x, y in zip(new_locs, new_locs[1:]))
```

Comment: idxes here must be without replacement. Also, not sure why kept is shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `random` module

**Ex:**

```
import random

A = [ 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 ]
result = A[2:5]
del A[2:5]
while A:
    l = len(A)
    result.insert(random.randint(0, l), A.pop(random.randrange(l)))
print(result)
```

**Demo**

```
def rand_shfl(lst):
    result = lst[2:5]
    del lst[2:5]
    while A:
        l = len(A)
        result.insert(random.randint(0, l), A.pop(random.randrange(l)))
    return result

for _ in range(10):
    A = [ 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 ]
    print((rand_shfl(A)))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 7, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2]
[8, 1, 2, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4]
[8, 6, 7, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 8, 5, 3, 4, 6]
[6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2]
[7, 2, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4, 8]
[1, 8, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 8, 4, 2]
[1, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 8, 6]
[8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: works well for the example shown. But perhaps worth to make this more generic. 
e.g., when 5, 3, and 4 do not occur consecutively in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Probably below will work for you

```
import random
lst=[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
s_lst = {5:0,3:0,4:0}

idx_lst = [random.randint(0, len(lst)) for i in range(len(s_lst))]
idx_lst.sort()

for i, s in enumerate(s_lst.keys()):
    s_lst[s] = idx_lst[i]
    lst.remove(s)

random.shuffle(lst)
for k, v in s_lst.items():
    lst.insert(v, k)

print(lst)
```